# is this the proper initialization of 2d dynamic array that stores floats?

Tags: c++, arrays

well i had the 2d array  but for some reason i need it to be dynamic now 
so it was like this

```cpp
const int n=100;  const int m=100;
float matrix1 [n][m];
```

and i tried to make it like this

```cpp
int n,m ;
float** matrix1 = new int*[n];
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    matrix1[i] = new int[m];
```

**i need all the elements inside the array to be floats**

Comment: instead of `new int*[n]` use `new float*[n]`, and instead of `new int[m]` use `new float[m]`

Comment: @ChrisRollins can i initialize this array under the including area out side all the functions ?

Comment: it is possible to declare the pointer globally but you can't run a for loop in the global scope, so you'd have to have the initialization occur in a function.

Comment: ohh thank you. its like 3 hours i've been trying to write a for loop globally

Comment: @YusufSameh [Please see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21943621/how-to-create-a-contiguous-2d-array-in-c/21944048#21944048).  Your method of creating the array is one of the worst ways of doing this.

Answer (score 3):

Avoid this approach, it'll trash your cache access. Use a 1d array, and create a function that can access elements via 2 indices.

Otherwise, std::vector is safer to use than a raw pointer and comes with almost no performance penalties in release builds.

Like:

```
unsigned int n = 100;
unsigned int m = 1000;

std::vector<float> data(n * m, 0.0f);

auto accessor = [&](unsigned int x, unsigned int y) -> float& {
    // optional bounds checks here
    return data[x + y * n];
};

// Do something with your data.
accessor(1, 2) = 1.0f;
```

A better approach would be to wrap it up in a struct/class that also stores dimensions.

Comment: [An example of wrapping the `vector` in a class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076668/4581301)